# c - integer downcast

Tags: c, type-conversion

About integer numbers downcasts in C, e.g.

An int value `000F'E000` downcast to short or unsigned short will become `E000`. 
`short` -> `-8192`,
`unsigned short`  -> `57344`,

So does it simply cut the bits?

And what about upcasts? E.g. int `-10` is `ffffff81`, what is the rule to cast to `long long`?

---

**@Update**

About upcasting, according to the answers I did some tests and found that with 2's complement it has the following rules:

```
    signed:
        positive -> positive: add 0 as prefix bits,
        negative -> negative: add 1 as prefix bits,
    unsigned:
        add 0 as prefix bits,
```

**code:**

```
// integer numbers, downcast & upcast,
#include <stdio.h>

void downcastTest() {
    int i = 127<<13;
    printf("%X, %hX, %hi\n", i, i, i);
}

void upcastTest() {
    int i = 127;
    int j = -127;
    printf("%x, %llx\n", i, (long long)i);
    printf("%x, %llx\n", j, (long long)j);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    downcastTest();
    upcastTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value would you expect to get by "upcasting" `E000`?

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks for tip, corrected to `cast`, about upcasting I have updated the question.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19262851/694576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rule for C to cast between short and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262851/what-is-the-rule-for-c-to-cast-between-short-and-int)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Downcasts

A cast to a smaller integer type discards the most significant (left-most as you'd write the full binary integer on paper) bits that are not present in the destination type.

#### Upcasts

An upcast to a larger integer is more complex:

- For **unsigned** to **unsigned** types, it adds sufficient zero most-significant bytes; this always preserves the value.
- For **signed** to **signed** types, it sign-extends the the source type (i.e. packs the new byte(s) with bits equal to the sign bit of the source integer); this always preserves the value, positive or negative
- For **unsigned** to **signed** types, it effectively adds sufficient zero-most significant bytes; this always preserves the value, as in the nature of an upcast, there are always more bits in the destination, so there is always space for an extra sign 'bit'
- For **signed** to **unsigned** types, it sign-extends, then casts; this cannot always preserve the value, as a negative value cannot be represented.

Comment: Thanks, I think any correct program shouldn't cast from signed value to unsigned value.

Comment: I would avoid using the term `left most` because some machines are big endian and some are small endian

Comment: @JamesWierzba I've clarified, but to be honest on a little endian machine there is no difference in left/right vs. a big endian machine, as byte order has no left/right connotations.

Comment: This is generally incorrect, you perhaps describe behaviour for some particular platforms

Comment: Good point. I guess it's more a issue of cultural language semantics then, since some languages are left-to-right and others are right-to-left

Comment: @M.M I believe I am describing the behaviour set out in the C standard - from memory C99 6.3.1.1. Of course there may be platforms that don't follow the C standard, but this question is about C. If I've read the standard wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The standard doesn't support any of your points other than "for unsigned to unsigned types" or "for unsigned to signed types". The standard never specifies sign-extension.

Comment: My apologies. It's 6.3.1.8

Answer (score 1):

Downcast cuts the bits, up-cast depends on "signedness". Up-cast on unsigned types adds zero bits to the value, up-cast on signed types replicates the sign bit. In this way, the expression has the same value before and after an upcast.

Answer (score 1):

For converting anything to an unsigned type, the value is adjusted modulo `TYPE_MAX+1` until it is in range of the unsigned type.   Example: `-10` converted to `uint16_t` which has a range of 0-65535 results in `65536-10` or `65526`.

For converting anything to a signed type: If the original value is in the range of the signed type, that is the result. Otherwise the behaviour is *implementation-defined*, which includes the possibility of raising a signal. The compiler must document its behaviour for this case.

Example: `-10` converted to `long long` results in a `long long` of value `-10`. The bit representation doesn't matter, the rules are based on values.

---

Your test program contains a lot of undefined behaviour due to using the wrong format specifier in `printf`. (In fact every single format specifier is wrong for the argument given). Being undefined behaviour, the output is meaningless so do not try and "learn" from this program.  Instead you can study the rules in the Standard or other answers on this site, and read your compiler's documentation.